# Programmatic fragment within fragment within viewpager duplication

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a very simple ToDo list app with multiple categories the user can add an item to. The architecture looks something like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UbOd.png

I am using a ViewPager and each view is a fragment that I instantiate in the ViewPagerAdapater:

```
public Fragment getItem(int i) {
    ToDoCategoryModel cat = categories().get(i);
    ToDoCategoryView view = ToDoCategoryView.newInstance(cat);
    return view;
}
```

Within each of these category the user can add new Item Fragments to a Linear Layout.

A very strange thing happens though. I start off on Category 1 (C1) Which currently has 1 Item in the list. Then scroll to C2 then scroll again to C3. Then I scroll back to C2. The ViewPager asks my ViewPagerAdapter to re-create C1 as it was destroyed after having scrolled 2 pages away from it. This is fine, I just create a brand new fragment (as the code above shows). However, when I now scroll back to C1, instead of 1 Item being shown (as you would expect) there are 2 items shown. They are a duplicate of each other.

The code I use to add the Item fragment to the Category fragment is:

```
public void addToDoItem(ToDoItemModel model) {
    ToDoItemView newItem = ToDoItemView.newInstance(model, this);
    getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(_linearLayout_items.getId(), newItem, "sameTag"+count++).commit();
}
```

If I change this code to add new TextView instead of fragments:

```
public void addToDoItem(ToDoItemModel model) {
    ToDoItemView newItem = ToDoItemView.newInstance(model, this);
    TextView tv = new TextView(getActivity());
    tv.setText(newItem.getModel().getName());
    _linearLayout_items.addView(tv);
}
```

It works fine! There are no duplicate items shown.

So what is wrong with adding fragments dynamically using the child fragment manager within a view pager?

Thanks.

Comment: Couple of quick follow-on questions: is your adapter type a FragmentStatePagerAdapter or ...? Are you checking whether the ToDoItemView already exists before adding (so you can remove/replace instead)?

Comment: Yeah I am using the State one (FragmentStatePagerAdapter). No there is no check to see if the View exists already within the LinearLayout.

Comment: Is your number of categories fixed (C1, C2, C3 - no more)? Also, you mention C1 being destroyed when you page to C3...try specifying mPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2) and see if you get the same behaviour.

Comment: The number of categories is not fixed. There can be 0 or 100+. I expect if the page limit is set then I won't get this problem, however I think that is quite inefficient with the memory and doesn't really fix the original problem.

Comment: Any particular reason you're using a list of fragments inside each category vs. a custom view? It would make your code simpler and the issue would probably go away.

Comment: This is what I have now switched over to: a compound view. I thought Fragements would be a better way to do it though.